# Catalyst apps don't seem to support three-finger swipe gestures

Tags: macos, catalina, multi-touch, development

I finally updated to Catalina, and it doesn't seem that any Catalyst apps I've tested support three-finger swipe gestures - they seem to expect them to be done with two fingers regardless of this setting:

[image: System preferences trackpad swipe setting]

It's odd because every other Mac app seems to respect this setting, so two-finger swipes side-to-side scroll horizontally, and only three finger gestures will go back/forward. Alas, it seems catalyst apps completely ignore this. Does anyone know whether it's possible for developers to support three-finger gestures in their Catalyst apps, or is this just something that's broken at a framework level?